# How to combine dynamic Javascript div height resizing with in-page anchor hyperlinks?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, anchor

Ok, this is an unusual question, but I've been playing around with it for hours and haven't had any progress - hoping the SO community can help!

Here's the webpage in question: https://pifornerds.io/

We're using this code to dynamically set the background (the digits of pi that you see in grey) height based on the foreground content length:

```
<script>
      // Dynamically set base height based on container contents
      var containerHeight = document.getElementById("container").offsetHeight;
      var baseHeight = document.getElementById("base").offsetHeight;
      if (baseHeight > containerHeight) {
        document.getElementById("base").style.height = containerHeight + "px";
      }
</script>
```

CSS snippet:

```
.layered {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: left;
  background-color: #222222;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.layered > * {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.base {
  font-family: "DejaVuSansMonoBold", courier;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.1;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  word-break: break-all;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: static;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  height: max-content;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

We wanted to do this so there wouldn't be a bunch of pi digits in the footer area. We think it looks "cleaner" this way.

However, the menu at the top uses anchor links to jump to content lower on the page, for example:

`<a href="#roadmap">Roadmap</a>`

jumps to:

`<a id="roadmap"></a>`

Now here's the problem ...

After you click a menu anchor link, and then try to scroll back up the page to the top, **you can't**  ... because somehow the previous Javascript height update won't allow that.

This is as far up as I can scroll up now, after clicking "Roadmap":

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/imkane/kof83msy/4/
Of course it works properly there

Comment: Hi ! "Somehow" the script wont allow that may be a board effect of forcing sizes via javascript. I did it many times in the past, but I completely gave up this habit. I'd like to work on your case, but pleaaaaase post an html example here ;)

Comment: Yes of course I can view source, but it which way will this question be useful to other readers ? I see below that your site has been patched, this is good news for you, everything goes fine.

Comment: @Philippe unfortunately, no, the problem isn't resolved. See comments below. This question will be useful for other users, because it's a JS/CSS issue, not an HTML issue.

Comment: I don't agree with you, but it does not matter in fact. Good luck and happy coding :)

Comment: I added a Fiddle, and of course it works properly there lol. But not on the live site. Doh.  https://jsfiddle.net/imkane/kof83msy/4/

Comment: Hey Kane ! Can you isolate the source of the issue now ?

Comment: @Philippe unfortunately, no :(

Comment: Bad news :( I've just try  to host the parts of your fiddle on my test server, and of course everything is ok, except for the fonts loading. Even if I go on our live site, I'm not able to notice any behavior issue with Chrome on Windows10 Oo

Comment: @Philippe that's odd - on every browser and device, the bottom part of the page should have the background pi #s not as long as the content. I checked in FireFox, Chrome, and Android. This is because the JS to get the #container height isn't working properly - it's returning a height that's too small.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `overflow: hidden;` from `.layered` div.
It will probably be better to add `overflow: hidden;` to `.base` div, which is the one you set the height on.

Comment: Thanks for your help! That fixed the anchor link scroll bug, but now the background pi digits aren't as long as the text content. I tried just adding 200px extra, but that's not a responsive solution (ie on phones it looks much different than desktops).

Comment: Screenshot (I wish SO would let you attach images to comments):  https://ibb.co/Nm7mWKS

Comment: So at this point, the height of base is wrong.
It looks like `document.getElementById("container").offsetHeight;` is returning the correct height. so remove the `if` statement `if (baseHeight > containerHeight) {` and just set the height.

Comment: Unfortunately there seems to be an issue with calculating the container height. Check the console log - every method returns 2992.2px, yet the ACTUAL height of that div is 3165px. Crazy eh??